# github v3 api create comment failing

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to create a comment with Github's api, but it's failing, and I'm looking for debugging tips.

I'm using the url listed in the api docs, which correctly returns a list of comments for a GET request. When I try to do a POST request, I get a 404 response. I'm using an Ajax request from a browser with cors, and I have an OAuth token in the 'Authorization' header field.

The url looks like:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/commits/sha/comments
```

The post body looks like:

```
{"body":"hello!","commit_id":"same_as_sha_in_url","line":79,"path":"path/to/file.js","position":2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. It was apparently because my OAuth scope was read-only. Adding 'public_repo' and 'repo' to my OAuth scope fixed the problem.